# How to store elements in a 2D array and print it (whist reading from a file)

Tags: java

ok so heres my code now .u guys might react with a faceplam but after alot of confusion this is what i came up with now, plz correct all my errors( i suck in programing i know!)

```
Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Documents and Settings\\UserXP\\My Documents\\src\\file.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line="";
ArrayList<String>arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
while((line=in.nextLine())!=null){
  arrayList.add(line);
  System.out.println(line);

}




         char [][] array = new char [2337][];
            for (int row = 0; row<array.length; row++)


                 if(line=in.nextLine())!=null)
                for(int col = 0; col<line.length(); col++)
                {
                    array[row][col] = line.charAt(col);

                    System.out.print(""+ array[row][col]);
                         }
                         System.out.println("");
                }
}
```

this is the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    at read_file.main(read_file.java:129)

**if(line=in.nextLine())!=null)** is line 129

Comment: iv only shown the relevant portion of my code where the error is coming

Comment: if you could give me the meaning of this error, or tell me what could possibly be the fault...(im quite new in programming)

Comment: Which line happens the error?

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, you're reading a line and *assuming* that it will have at least 34 characters. Presumably that's not the case for the file you're reading.

This is the line which is giving you the problem:

```
array[row][col] = ss.charAt(col);
```

Why would you assume that `ss` contained at least 34 characters? You could always add a check for that:

```
String ss = in.nextLine();
if (ss.length() < array[row].length) {
    // Handle this however you want, e.g. throwing a contextually-useful
    // exception or skipping the line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here another version of code which can help you to get your data  and assign them to array

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFileTo2DArray {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in;
        char array[][]=new char[2337][];
        try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Documents and Settings\\UserXP\\My Documents\\src\\file.txt"));

            String line="";
            int lineNuumber=0;
            while(in.hasNext() && (line=in.nextLine())!=null){
                array[lineNuumber]=new char[line.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                    array[lineNuumber][i]=line.charAt(i);
                    System.out.print(""+array[lineNuumber][i]);
                }

              System.out.println("");
              lineNuumber++;
            }

            System.out.println("total number of lines:"+lineNuumber);
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

}
```

Just one thing:
- it works ok  in case there are 2337 lines in file or less ..if there are more lines you will get an exception .. because you initialized array with 2337 which means you don't have space to store more.

hope this will solve your problem ..

good luck

Comment: ^ (done this and iv got:) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at read_file.main(read_file.java:121)

Comment: how to remove this error, i read to need the whole file

Comment: I updated the code and add  if(ss!=null) since it looks that file doesn't contain 2337 lines ..

Comment: do you still have the error ? show us code by which you read the file

Comment: iv edited my original code, see from there

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the problem with how your processing each line in the file. But in addition to all that you have another problem in your code. If the file contains less than 2337 lines you are eventually going to get an NPE (because of your outer loop). You need to check if the read line is null and break out of the loop if true.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the ss String has less than 34 characters in some situations. Actually way you initialize not too good. Instead you could dynamically add the values to your array. Otherwise in cases where you do not need such a large array, still you will allocate the memory.

And for the  checking  you can use ss.lenght() rather than go for the array size

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the length of the array but read the characters from a string that might be shorter.

Example:

Let `ss` be the string `"test"` and `col` be 5 (according to your code `col` can have any value between 0 and 33). If you want to get the 6th character (index 5) from `"test"` you'll see a problem: the string only has 4 characters.

Thus either loop over the length of the line (up to the length of the array, use `Math.max()` here) or break the inner loop once the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the length of string that you are reading from the file. If the length of the string is less than the number of columns, the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

if u really need to write the chars from file into a 2d array, then i d do it like this

```
int counter =0;
char[][] array = new char[2000][34];
char c ="";
while((c = ss.charAt(counter++))!=null){
        array[counter%2000][counter/2000]=c;
        if(counter/2000 => 34-1) //then not enought space
```

the counter will run from your charAt(1,..,n).
counter/2000 will break down the row, counter%34 the col.

eg charAt(36) will be stored at array[36][0].
charAt(3023) wil be stored at array[1023][1].

maybe there is a syntax misstake in the while loop, but the idea will work ;).