# Getting a NullPointerException - how to remove it?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm new in programming.

```
array [row][col] = line.charAt(col);
```

^ this the line is where I'm getting `NullPointerException` in my code.  How to remove it?

```
Scanner in = null;
try {
    in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Documents and Settings\\UserXP\\My Documents\\src\\file.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
String line="";
ArrayList<String>arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

while((line=in.nextLine())!=null) {
    arrayList.add(line);
    char [][] array = new char [2337][];
    for (int row = 0; row<arrayList.size(); row++)
        for(int col = 0; col<line.length(); col++) {
            array [row][col] = line.charAt(col);
            System.out.print(""+ array[row][col]);
        }
    System.out.println("");
}

//Close the input stream
in.close();
```

Comment: i dont know how to remove this exception

Comment: pls add the stack trace to your question as well

Comment: Are you posting questions under multiple id's? 2337 is such a random number to pick for array initialization that I can't help but think this is also you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017838/how-to-store-elements-in-a-2d-array-and-print-it-whist-reading-from-a-file

Comment: im not allowed to ask more questions from that account :( ......and i have got till midnight to submit this programme im in alot of tension...so yes i confess iv signed up again

Answer (score 7):

You're never allocating any memory for the second dimension of your array:

```
char [][] array = new char [2337][];
```

Gives you 2337 `char[]`s but all of them are null.

You'll need

```
array[row] = new char[line.length()];
```

before the column loop.

EDIT (clarify where to insert):

```
for (int row = 0; row<arrayList.size(); row++) {
    array[row] = new char[line.length()];
    for(int col = 0; col<line.length(); col++) {
        array [row][col] = line.charAt(col);
        System.out.print(""+ array[row][col]);
    }
}
```

Note also, as your logic appears inefficient, as you're recreating rows every time you're adding a line.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at read_file.main(read_file.java:115)

Comment: while((line=in.nextLine())!=null){ is the line

Comment: can you tell me what does the exception mean?

Comment: The `Scanner` object is closed, so somewhere you are accessing the `in` variable after your call to `in.close()`.